# Предотвращение засыпания системы и проблемы с последующим засыпанием

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi

Суть задачи:

В течении некоторого времени необходимо поддерживать систему в работающем состоянии не позволяя уходить в режим ожидания.
Для этого я периодически(благо и так есть метод который выполняется раз в 30 секунд) вызываю функцию `WinApi`:

`EXECUTION_STATE SetThreadExecutionState(EXECUTION_STATE esFlags)`

с флагами `ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED` и `ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED`

Вот листинг приложения на котором у меня удалось проявить эту проблему:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void KeepAlive()
        {
            Win32.SetThreadExecutionState(
                Win32.EXECUTION_STATE.ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED |
                Win32.EXECUTION_STATE.ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged += SystemEvents_PowerModeChanged;

            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(50 * 1000);
                Console.WriteLine("Timer resetted: " + DateTime.Now);
                KeepAlive();
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void SystemEvents_PowerModeChanged(object sender, PowerModeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("power mode changed to: " + e.Mode);
        }
    }

    static class Win32
    {
        [FlagsAttribute]
        public enum EXECUTION_STATE : uint
        {
            ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED = 0x00000040,
            ES_CONTINUOUS = 0x80000000,
            ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED = 0x00000002,
            ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED = 0x00000001
            // Legacy flag, should not be used.
            // ES_USER_PRESENT = 0x00000004
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern EXECUTION_STATE SetThreadExecutionState(EXECUTION_STATE esFlags);

    }
}
```

Таймер перехода в спящий режим установлен на 1 мин.

При выполнении этого приложения получается вот такая картина:
Запускается приложение, через 50 секунд вызывается функция и система продолжает работать ещё 1 минуту не уходя в режим сна.
Спустя эту минуту монитор выключается, но система не переходит в режим ожидания.

Вопросы:
Почему система не засыпает по истечению таймера?

Как добиться того что-бы система уснула во время выполнения приложения по истечению таймера простоя?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема оказалась не в приложении, а в настройке режима электропитания компьютера.
Всем спасибо за проявленный интерес.