# Как отключить переход в спящий режим, когда работает программа?

Tags: c#

Написал программу, которая должна работать круглосуточно, поставил ее на ноутбук.

Как она работет:

Есть рассписание и если в определенные промежутки времени срабатывает условие, то программа выполняет определенные действия, иначе если это не тот промежуток времени или если условие не срабатывает, то программа просто крутит зацикленное видео. Так вот, если долго не срабатывет условие, то даже не смотря на то, что видео идет, компьютер переходит в спящий режим.

Пробовал через powercfg.cpl, поставил "Отключать дисплей" и "Переводить компьютер в спящий режим" на НИКОГДА, но не помогло.

Скажите пожалуйста, как это можно поправить?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Предотвращение засыпания системы и проблемы с последующим засыпанием](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/683921/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот [тут](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6cac1cdf-bc36-4a29-99e1-04e25fa3816f/c-prevent-sleep-mode-programmatically?forum=csharpgeneral) перечислены следующие варианты:

1. Вызывать у экземпляра класса `DisplayRequest` метод `RequestActive`
2. Воспользоваться WinAPI `SetThreadExecutionState` и вызвать как-то так([сорс](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6302309/4244707)):

   ```
   // Set new state to prevent system sleep
   fPreviousExecutionState = NativeMethods.SetThreadExecutionState(
               NativeMethods.ES_CONTINUOUS | NativeMethods.ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED);

   internal static class NativeMethods
   {
       // Import SetThreadExecutionState Win32 API and necessary flags
       [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
       public static extern uint SetThreadExecutionState(uint esFlags);
       public const uint ES_CONTINUOUS = 0x80000000;
       public const uint ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED = 0x00000001;
   }
   ```
3. Слушать `WM_POWERBROADCAST` сообщение. ([Сорс](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/385c3b38-fb74-4bb8-b064-c2392c8f46d0/how-to-prevent-hibernatesuspend-on-a-desktop-in-vista?forum=csharpgeneral) [EnSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/732045/4244707))

   ```
   protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
   {
       // Power status event triggered
       if(m.Msg == (int)WindowMessage.WM_POWERBROADCAST)
       {
           // Machine is trying to enter suspended state
           if(m.WParam.ToInt32() == (int)WindowMessage.PBT_APMQUERYSUSPEND ||
                   m.WParam.ToInt32() == (int)WindowMessage.PBT_APMQUERYSTANDBY)
           {
               // Have perms to deny this message?
               if((m.LParam.ToInt32() & 0x1) != 0)
               {
                   // If so, deny broadcast message
                   m.Result = new IntPtr((int)WindowMessage.BROADCAST_QUERY_DENY);
               }
           }
           return;
       }

       base.WndProc(ref m);
   }
   ```

   }

   ```
       internal enum WindowMessage
   {

   /// <summary>
   /// Notify that machine power state is changing
   /// </summary>
   WM_POWERBROADCAST = 0x218,
   /// <summary>
   /// Message indicating that machine is trying to enter suspended state
   /// </summary>
   PBT_APMQUERYSUSPEND = 0x0,
   PBT_APMQUERYSTANDBY = 0x0001,

   /// <summary>
   /// Message to deny broadcast query
   /// </summary>
   BROADCAST_QUERY_DENY = 0x424D5144
   }
   ```

Comment: Почему-то код не форматируется. Подскажите, где у меня косяк?=(

Comment: Поправил. Код внутри списков как-то странно работает, лучше этого избегать.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, внутри списков надо 8 пробелов просто